# Passing parameters to callback function using RegisterWaitForSingleObject in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, process, callback

i'm trying to make a program that detects the process termination by the given process id. But i can't give any parameters to the callback function. How can i achieve this? 
Thanks.

```
void CALLBACK WaitOrTimerCallback(
     _In_  PVOID lpParameter, 
     _In_  BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired,
     DWORD processID)   
{   
    MessageBox(0, L"The process has exited.", L"INFO", MB_OK);  
    std::cout << processID << std::endl;  
    return;  
}  

int main()  
{  
    DWORD dwProcessID = 1234;  
    HANDLE hProcHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcessID);
    HANDLE hNewHandle;  
    RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&hNewHandle, hProcHandle, WaitOrTimerCallback(?, ?, dwProcessID), NULL, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE);  
}
```

Comment: You don't pass any parameters there, just the function pointer. What should be passed to the callback is specified in the other parameters of the `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` function. I'd recommend you read the MSDN documentation thotoughly again, and have a look at the examples.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i couldn't find any samples about what i need on the net. Can you share some source link?

Comment: What you want is to specify a value for the `Context` parameter and cast it to be whatever you are sure it is from the `PVOID` pointer instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` has a `Context` parameter for exactly the purpose of passing user-defined data to the callback.  For example:

```
void CALLBACK WaitOrTimerCallback(
     _In_  PVOID lpParameter, 
     _In_  BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)   
{   
    DWORD dwProcessID = reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(lpParameter);
    MessageBox(0, L"The process has exited.", L"INFO", MB_OK);  
    std::cout << dwProcessID << std::endl;  
}  

int main()  
{  
    DWORD dwProcessID = 1234;  
    HANDLE hProcHandle = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, dwProcessID);
    if (hProcHandle)
    {
        HANDLE hNewHandle;  
        if (RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&hNewHandle, hProcHandle, &WaitOrTimerCallback, reinterpret_cast<void*>(dwProcessID), INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE))
            UnregisterWait(hNewHandle);
        CloseHandle(hProcHandle);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Though, in this particular example, using `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` with an `INFINITE` timeout is overkill when `WaitForSingleObject()` would suffice:

```
int main()  
{  
    DWORD dwProcessID = 1234;  
    HANDLE hProcHandle = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, dwProcessID);
    if (hProcHandle)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject(hProcHandle, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            MessageBox(0, L"The process has exited.", L"INFO", MB_OK);  
            std::cout << dwProcessID << std::endl;  
        }
        CloseHandle(hProcHandle);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` should be used when you want to wait on an object asynchronously in the background while you move on to do other things in the meantime.  Don't wait on the wait operation.  The OS will notify you when the object is signaled.